# not a GROUP BY expression

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

i've following select:

```
Select attribut1, dateattribut, attribut3, 
       attribut4, attribut15, town_CODE, count(*)     
from (
select attribut1, dateattribut, attribut3, attribut4, attribut15, (CASE 
  WHEN  TO_CHAR(dateattribut,'YYYY')  = '2005'  THEN 
   CASE town_CODE 
    WHEN '039' THEN  '078' WHEN '050' THEN  '093' 
    WHEN '091' THEN  '008' WHEN '102' THEN  '093' 
   ELSE town_CODE end 
  ELSE town_CODE end) as town_CODE
from towntable) GROUP BY attribut1, dateattribut, 
                        attribut3, attribut4, 
                        attribut15, town_CODE
having count(*) > 1;
```

when i execute this query on our server it work fine. but on the server of my customer i get the oracle error `ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression`.

As far i found out that im having problems with the Case's and with the alias.
with out this it works.

any suggestions?

*what i'm trying to do with this statement is to get all double entry's. with the inner query i change all old codes to the new one, and then i want to group them to see if they exists multiply times.
Some customers did used old codes and now its possible that they have the same town 2 times.

**edit**

`SELECT * FROM product_component_version`

and i get on both:

```
Product                                     Version         Status

NLSRTL                                      10.2.0.4.0      Production
Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition      10.2.0.4.0      64bi
PL/SQL                                      10.2.0.4.0      Production
TNS for 64-bit Windows:                     10.2.0.4.0      Production
```

**edit2**

my test showed me that he doesn't like calling with the alias.
is there a setting, that alias are not recognized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is to use an View.

Inner Select as View and then the outer select as normal, and it works fine.

i found out that he doesn't like town_CODE in the outer select.

```
Select attribut1, dateattribut, attribut3,
       attribut4, attribut15, town_CODE, count(*)     
from  v_towntable
GROUP BY attribut1, dateattribut, attribut3, 
         attribut4, attribut15, town_CODE
having count(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 3):

> "when i execute this query on our server it work fine. but on the
>   server of my customer i get the oracle error `ORA-00979: not a GROUP
>   BY expression.`"

This means one of two things:

1. Your server is different from your customer's server and that difference prevents an error; for example, your server is a later version or has a different patch level.
2. You are not in fact running the same code on your customer's database as you run on your own.

The latter seems quite likely, as the code you posted *here* obviously isn't the code you run on your own server.  As others have pointed out, it contains a couple of syntax errors although neither would in fact hurl ORA-00979.

That error means you have a non-aggregate column in the projection which isn't in the GROUP BY clause or perhaps you have something in the GROUP BY clause which isn't in the projection.

Comment: well Nr.2 is it not coze the code is identical. or copy&paste changes the code. for DB version a select `SELECT * FROM product_component_version ;` shows the same result (see my post)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a bracket after the table name plus a comma after attribut15. Try this:

```
Select attribut1, dateattribut, attribut3, 
       attribut4, attribut15, town_CODE, count(*)     
from (
select attribut1, dateattribut, attribut3, attribut4, attribut15, (CASE 
  WHEN  TO_CHAR(dateattribut,'YYYY')  = '2005'  THEN 
   CASE town_CODE 
    WHEN '039' THEN  '078' WHEN '050' THEN  '093' 
    WHEN '091' THEN  '008' WHEN '102' THEN  '093' 
   ELSE town_CODE end 
  ELSE town_CODE end) as town_CODE
from towntable) GROUP BY attribut1, dateattribut, 
                        attribut3, attribut4, 
                        attribut15, town_CODE
having count(*) > 1;
```

Comment: well it was just a typo the actual query is a little bigger (some more changes for this attribut)

Comment: If you run only my code from above on both servers do you get any error?

Comment: still the same error :-(  i found out when i remove town_code in the first select it works. but then i don't know which town it its.

Answer (score 0):

There appear to be one or two syntax errors in the original query - the following should work:

```
Select attribut1, 
       dateattribut, 
       attribut3, 
       attribut4, 
       attribut15, 
       town_CODE, 
       count(*)     
from (select attribut1, 
             dateattribut, 
             attribut3, 
             attribut4, 
             attribut15,
             CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(dateattribut,'YYYY') = '2005' THEN 
                  CASE town_CODE 
                       WHEN '039' THEN  '078' 
                       WHEN '050' THEN  '093' 
                       WHEN '091' THEN  '008' 
                       WHEN '102' THEN  '093' 
                       ELSE town_CODE
                  end 
                  ELSE town_CODE
             end as town_CODE
      from towntable) v 
GROUP BY attribut1, 
         dateattribut, 
         attribut3, 
         attribut4, 
         attribut15, 
         town_CODE
having count(*) > 1
```

Comment: @rageit (incorrectly) changing the casing in questions are *not* valid edits